# Applescript Microsoft Outlook Forwarder

Tags: applescript, email, ms-office

So I'm new at Applescript and am trying to create a script to forward emails sent to a specific recipient in a specific folder in Outlook. It's failing for some reason but doesn't throw any errors so I don't know what's wrong. Ideally I would like it to check for a specific recipient anywhere in the chain of recipients. Could someone help point me in the right direction?

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    
    activate
    if view of the first main window is not equal to "mail view" then
        set view of the first main window to mail view
    end if
    
    --set inbox and subfolders
    
    set myInbox to folder "Inbox" of default account
    set DONE to folder "DONE" of myInbox
    
    --set subscribed folder and subfolders
    
    set subscribedFolders to folder "Subscribed Public Folders" of default account
    set Webcast to folder id 259 of subscribedFolders
    
    --set main view to Webcast folder
    
    --set selected folder to Webcast
    set selected folder to inbox
    
    -- Get the messages selected in Outlook
    
    set currentMessages to current messages
    
    -- Check to make sure items are selected, if not then quit
    
    if ((count of currentMessages) < 1) then return
    
    -- Iterate through selected messages
    
    repeat with aMessage in currentMessages
        
        -- Get the account for the message
        
        set messageAccount to account of aMessage
        
        --log messageAccount
        -- Get the sender for the message
        -- set messageSender to sender of aMessage
        --log messageSender
        -- Get the recipients for the message. A message can have multiple recipients.
        -- Try to get the first to recipient
        try
            set messageRecipient to email address of to recipient 1 of aMessage
        on error
            try
                set messageRecipient to email address of cc recipient 1 of aMessage
            on error
                set messageRecipient to email address of bcc recipient 1 of aMessage
            end try
        end try
        
        if messageRecipient is "specificaddress@email.com" then
            set fwdMessage to forward theMessage without opening window
            make new recipient at fwdMessage ¬
                with properties {email address:{address:"forwardaddress@sendit.com"}}
        end if
        
    end repeat
    
end tell

end run
```

Comment: The 'try' statement gets rid of the error message so that it fails silently. If you turn on logging (Window > Log History) and then run the script, errors will be logged there (or just comment out the try statements). Just guessing but that whole try/try block looks kind of broken.

Comment: Can you get a list of each set of recipients? If so, then you could ask if list {to/cc/bcc} contains 'specificaddress' — either three lists or one combined.